# Detecting all admins that are logged in

Tags: wp-admin, users, login

I'm trying to find all users that are logged in to WordPress.

I can detect myself, but I want to be able to find the other admins. Here is my current code to find myself.

```
if (user_can( $current_user, 'administrator' )) {
      echo '<div class="admin"> User currently logged in "' 
          . $current_user->user_login . '"</div>';
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that WP has such build in functionality. You can check some plugins that does that, and reverse engineer it. Here is one - https://github.com/lesterchan/wp-useronline .

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress do not have a true concept of "logged in". Although the labels all around use the term, in the code the closest you get is something that might be called "authenticated users". The difference is that the authenticated user might be one that has his browser closed and therefor he is not "logged in".

To do what you want you will first need to define what does it mean for you to be "logged in" and implement some logic to detect it. For example you might use ajax to update that a user is still connected and remove the user from the "logged in" list if it didn't update for lets say 5 minutes.

It is not trivial but not very complex to implement.

Answer (score 0):

On init set a transient for, say, 5 min that keeps updating as long as the current user (in this case, any admin) is poking around. Dump a list of those active transients from a shortcode into a page. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Mark Kaplun said, you could probably have a look at [User Meta Sessions Tokens](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_meta_session_tokens/). They can tell you, if there is an active session for a specific user. But that does not mean, that the user is active on the site and doing something, just that he logged in successfully.

Anyway, don´t trust anyone that tells you to use `is_user_logged_in()`! That´s not how that function works.